# How to populate msql database with Audios html pages

Tags: mysql, html, templates, audio

I have a need to upload 4,000 small audios (~30 seconds long) not ringtones :)
Similarly I have 4,000 html files.
I came to know about mysql is the best way to work with such large quantities of data. 
however I do not know how to work with mysql database, how to organize the audio & html files. if there is a working example then I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: "I came to know about mysql is the best way to work with such large quantities of data". Where did you learn this? And these are **not** large quantities of data. Why do you think that using a database at all is a good solution for this?

Comment: Depending on how large these files are, it would probably be better to store the files on disk, and store information (including the path) to them in the MySQL database. When you get the files in the database... what were you planning on doing with them?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off storing the files as-is in a file system rather than as large blobs or text fields in a relational database?

Comment: each audio file is around 50kb and each html is around 8kb. I do not know what is the best way. I have everything on my local harddisk but I want to know how can I take this data and populate a database so that I can use it to call this data into a template. For a newbie like me a small working example would be of great help. I said using database is good because for my future expansion that data would grow to 24,000x7 . and I do not want to create 24k.x static pages

Comment: What do you mean by "call this data into a template"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store files directly in MySQL using BLOB data types. However, the best way is to store the audio files in a directory, and then just store the path to the file in the database. This is because, after a certain point, it is more efficient to store files in a file-system rather than in a database.

So your table could be,

```
CREATE TABLE audio_files {
        id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        path VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
}
```

As it stands, you probably would find there wouldn't be much of a performance difference because you are working with a small number of files - but for best practice and future scalability, put it in the file system!

Then to pull out the data from the database you could use a simple PHP script to query the database and pull out all the paths and print them to the screen as links. In the example below im using PDO for database access, but you could also use the more simplistic mysql_query() if thats how your accessing your db.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT id, path FROM audo_files");
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$query->execute();
$files = $query->fetchAll();
foreach($files as $file) {
      echo "<a href='" . $file['path'] . "'>" . $file['name'] . "</a>";
}
```

You would want to put your files in a publicly accessibly area on your web area e.g. in a folder assets/audio, and then just put a relative path in your database e.g. assets/audio/file1.mp3.

Comment: great, now comes my second question related to it, how would I retrieve that data from this database on to my template. should I ask a new question?

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but does the same holds true for the html pages as well or do I need to modify anything other than the name of the table.

Comment: do you mean for storing HTML pages? you could do it exactly the same way if thats how you wanted to do it.